# C++ Program compiled with QT does not find automatically QT dlls in Windows

Tags: windows, qt, cmake

I have succesfully compiled a QT program for windows. I can not directly run the program in the build directory. The Dependency Walker shows that the paths to Qt5Gui.dll Qt5Widgets.dll Qt5Core.dll are not found. I am copying the dlls to the build directory and the program runs as expected. My question is how can I avoid copying the dlls in the build directory. Is there an option that I should add to the CMakeLists.txt to help in this situation ? I am using windows 10.

Comment: Add the directory where the DLL files were installed to the global `PATH` environment variable? How to do that is more a question for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/tour) though.

Comment: It worked. Thank you for the quick reply.